# Image Slider not working when included it in php page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have downloaded a full width image slider from http://dandywebsolution.com/skdslider/

and I modified the slider page for my requirements as follows, where now it has only the slider with two images,

**slider.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>SKDSlider - Full Width Jquery Slider - Jquery Responsive Full Width Slider - Full Screen Slider- Simple Jquery Slider</title>
<meta name="description" content="A jquery light weight image slideshow plugin. Full width and fully responsive simple image slider with fade in and fade out effect.">
<meta name="keywords" content="jquery slideshow, full width slideshow, simple slideshow, simple image slider, responsive slider, full width responsive slider">
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
<meta name="copyright" content="Samir Das">
<meta name="language" content="EN">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="src/skdslider.js"></script>
<link href="src/skdslider.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery('#demo1').skdslider({delay:5000, animationSpeed: 2000,showNextPrev:true,showPlayButton:true,autoSlide:true,animationType:'fading',showNav:false});

            jQuery('#responsive').change(function(){
              $('#responsive_wrapper').width(jQuery(this).val());
            });

        });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
body{ margin:0; padding:0;}
.demo-code{ background-color:#ffffff; border:1px solid #333333; display:block; padding:10px;}
.option-table td{ border-bottom:1px solid #eeeeee;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="skdslider">
    <ul id="demo1" class="slides">
<li>
<img src="slides/slide1.png" />
<!--Slider Description example-->

</li>
<li><img src="slides/slide2.png" />

</li>

</ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

When running it alone it works great, But when I included it my Web Page as follows, it doesn't show anything but the space of the slider, please can anyone suggest me a solution

**index.php**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <title>DoIT</title>
      <link href="css/rwdgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <link href="css/localstyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <script src="scripts/script.js"></script>
      <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
      <script src="src/skdslider.js"></script>
      <link href="src/skdslider.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script type="text/javascript">
         jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery('#demo1').skdslider({delay:5000, animationSpeed: 2000,showNextPrev:true,showPlayButton:true,autoSlide:true,animationType:'fading',showNav:false});

            jQuery('#responsive').change(function(){
              $('#responsive_wrapper').width(jQuery(this).val());
            });

         });
      </script>
      <style type="text/css">
         body{ margin:0; padding:0;}
         .demo-code{ background-color:#ffffff; border:1px solid #333333; display:block; padding:10px;}
         .option-table td{ border-bottom:1px solid #eeeeee;}
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="page-wrap">
         <?php include 'header.php'; ?>
         <div class="fullwidth">
            <div class="skdslider">
               <ul id="demo1" class="slides">
                  <li>
                     <img src="slides/slide1.png" />
                     <!--Slider Description example-->
                  </li>
                  <li><img src="slides/slide2.png" />
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="fullwidth">
            <br /><br />
         </div>
         <div class="container-12">
            <div class="grid-4">
               <center>
                  <img src="images/professionas.png" width="128" height="128" />
               </center>
               <h2 align="center">Who We Are</h2>
               <p align="justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque eleifend vitae tellus non egestas. Suspendisse potenti. Praesent facilisis tincidunt scelerisque. Aliquam sed elementum neque. In sed imperdiet quam, ut blandit erat. Sed quis commodo mi. Curabitur at ultricies quam. Nullam malesuada mauris massa.</p>
               <center><input type="submit" class="btn" value="Read More" /></center>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-4">
               <center>
                  <img src="images/professor.png" width="128" height="128" />
               </center>
               <h2 align="center">Courses</h2>
               <p align="justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque eleifend vitae tellus non egestas. Suspendisse potenti. Praesent facilisis tincidunt scelerisque. Aliquam sed elementum neque. In sed imperdiet quam, ut blandit erat. Sed quis commodo mi. Curabitur at ultricies quam. Nullam malesuada mauris massa.</p>
               <center><input type="submit" class="btn" value="Read More" /></center>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-4">
               <center>
                  <img src="images/success_path.png" width="128" height="128" />
               </center>
               <h2 align="center">Solutions</h2>
               <p align="justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque eleifend vitae tellus non egestas. Suspendisse potenti. Praesent facilisis tincidunt scelerisque. Aliquam sed elementum neque. In sed imperdiet quam, ut blandit erat. Sed quis commodo mi. Curabitur at ultricies quam. Nullam malesuada mauris massa.</p>
               <center><input type="submit" class="btn" value="Read More" /></center>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="fullwidth">
            <br /><br />
         </div>
         <div class="container-12">
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
            <hr />
            <div class="grid-12">
               <h2>Latest</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-3">
               <img src="images/gaming.png" width="100%" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;" />
            </div>
            <div class="grid-9">
               <h2>DoIT Gaming Challange 2014</h2>
               <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque eleifend vitae tellus non egestas. Suspendisse potenti. Praesent facilisis tincidunt scelerisque. Aliquam sed elementum neque. In sed imperdiet quam, ut blandit erat. Sed quis commodo mi. Curabitur at ultricies quam. Nullam malesuada mauris massa. Ut fringilla risus sit amet arcu iaculis, sed egestas neque egestas. Aenean scelerisque tellus sed volutpat consequat. Donec volutpat sem ac dolor elementum bibendum.</p>
               <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Read More" />
            </div>
         </div>
         <div style="clear: both;"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="fullwidth"><br /><br /></div>
      <?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
      <script src="scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you post a jsfiddle?

Comment: You are including the jQuery library twice - why? And are you sure the `jquery.js` file exists in your `scripts` directory?

Comment: You are calling two instances of head tags . You need to take out the content between the head tags and add it to the index.php file.

Comment: @soktinpk Can I add multiple files there? since I have a php file as well as html

Comment: You can include the slider.html file as you have done. The include command is correct. HOWEVER, you must not have all that header information inside the included file! Also, when testing, I would advise NOT using include -- but actually copy/paste the code into the `.fullwidth` div, just to be sure everything is there. Once it is working, THEN go ahead and move some code into include files, if desired to streamline your main file.

Comment: @DilukshanMahendra No, you can't post php on jsfiddle, but can you post what the result of the php is? (That is, what html it produces for the specific pages)? You can view the exact html if you aren't sure by viewing page source.

Comment: @Ben I took out the head content and placed them in index head, but no luck yet

Comment: @soktinpk http://jsfiddle.net/ygk04na5/

Comment: you have included script.js twice. Have you noticed this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>DoIT</title>
  <meta name="description" content="A jquery light weight image slideshow plugin. Full width and fully responsive simple image slider with fade in and fade out effect.">
  <meta name="keywords" content="jquery slideshow, full width slideshow, simple slideshow, simple image slider, responsive slider, full width responsive slider">
  <meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
  <meta name="copyright" content="Samir Das">
  <meta name="language" content="EN">
      <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="src/skdslider.js"></script>
 <link href="src/skdslider.css" rel="stylesheet"><link href="css/rwdgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="css/localstyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="scripts/script.js"></script>
  <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 </head>
  <body>

  <div class="page-wrap">
      <?php include 'header.php'; ?>
     <div class="fullwidth">
        <?php include 'slider.html'; ?>
     </div>
     <div class="fullwidth">
        <br /><br />
     </div>
     <div class="container-12">
        <div class="grid-4">
           <center>
              <img src="images/professionas.png" width="128" height="128" />
           </center>
           <h2 align="center">Who We Are</h2>
           <p align="justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque eleifend vitae tellus non egestas. Suspendisse potenti. Praesent facilisis tincidunt scelerisque. Aliquam sed elementum neque. In sed imperdiet quam, ut blandit erat. Sed quis commodo mi. Curabitur at ultricies quam. Nullam malesuada mauris massa.</p>
           <center><input type="submit" class="btn" value="Read More" /></center>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-4">
           <center>
              <img src="images/professor.png" width="128" height="128" />
           </center>
           <h2 align="center">Courses</h2>
           <p align="justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque eleifend vitae tellus non egestas. Suspendisse potenti. Praesent facilisis tincidunt scelerisque. Aliquam sed elementum neque. In sed imperdiet quam, ut blandit erat. Sed quis commodo mi. Curabitur at ultricies quam. Nullam malesuada mauris massa.</p>
           <center><input type="submit" class="btn" value="Read More" /></center>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-4">
           <center>
              <img src="images/success_path.png" width="128" height="128" />
           </center>
           <h2 align="center">Solutions</h2>
           <p align="justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque eleifend vitae tellus non egestas. Suspendisse potenti. Praesent facilisis tincidunt scelerisque. Aliquam sed elementum neque. In sed imperdiet quam, ut blandit erat. Sed quis commodo mi. Curabitur at ultricies quam. Nullam malesuada mauris massa.</p>
           <center><input type="submit" class="btn" value="Read More" /></center>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="fullwidth">
        <br /><br />
     </div>
     <div class="container-12">
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        <hr />
        <div class="grid-12">
           <h2>Latest</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-3">
           <img src="images/gaming.png" width="100%" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;" />
        </div>
        <div class="grid-9">
           <h2>DoIT Gaming Challange 2014</h2>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque eleifend vitae tellus non egestas. Suspendisse potenti. Praesent facilisis tincidunt scelerisque. Aliquam sed elementum neque. In sed imperdiet quam, ut blandit erat. Sed quis commodo mi. Curabitur at ultricies quam. Nullam malesuada mauris massa. Ut fringilla risus sit amet arcu iaculis, sed egestas neque egestas. Aenean scelerisque tellus sed volutpat consequat. Donec volutpat sem ac dolor elementum bibendum.</p>
           <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Read More" />
        </div>
     </div>
     <div style="clear: both;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="fullwidth"><br /><br /></div>
  <?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

Slider.html

```
  <div class="skdslider">
    <ul id="demo1" class="slides">
    <li>
<img src="slides/slide1.png" />
<!--Slider Description example-->

</li>
<li><img src="slides/slide2.png" />

</li>

</ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Add this to your styles.css

```
 body{ margin:0; padding:0;}
.demo-code{ background-color:#ffffff; border:1px solid #333333; display:block; padding:10px;}
.option-table td{ border-bottom:1px solid #eeeeee;}
```

Add this too your main js file

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery('#demo1').skdslider({delay:5000, animationSpeed: 2000,showNextPrev:true,showPlayButton:true,autoSlide:true,animationType:'fading',showNav:false});

            jQuery('#responsive').change(function(){
              $('#responsive_wrapper').width(jQuery(this).val());
            });

        });
```

Hope this helps

Comment: You could just add the slider.html content to your main php file

Comment: Ben is right -- this should work. +1 [Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sL0nom0v/) (Ben, you are welcome to include it in your answer).

Comment: @Ben I did exactly what you shown here, but for some reason still it displays the space but no images, :(

Comment: Have you included your images. Did you make a spelling mistake?

Answer (score 0):

try putting your `<script src="scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` just before the closing of the body tag.